# Are bronchioles and alveoli covered by respiratory epithelium?

Tags: human-anatomy

Which parts of respiratory apparatus are covered by respiratory epithelium and which are covered by other kinds of epithelium?

Comment: What do you mean by respiratory epithelium ? Do you mean squamous epithelium ?

Answer (score 1):

*From the nose to the pharynx and larynx*: **stratified squamous epithelium**

*From the end of larynx to the bronchi*: **pseudostratified columnar ciliated epithelial cells**.

From the small bronchi cartilage is being replaced by elastic tissue.

*Bronchioles*: **ciliated simple epithelium with [club cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_cell)** (known as Clara cells). Also they lack cartilage and glands.

*Alveoli* are covered with **squamous alveolar cells** which form the wall (also known as type I pneumocytes). They also contain great alveolar cells (which produce surfactant) or type II pneumocytes and macrophages.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respiratory_tract , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulmonary_alveolus and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharynx

Answer (score 0):

The major parts of respiratory apparatus are covered by ciliated respiratory epithelium with goblet cells.
The trachea and bronchi are covered by pseudostratified columnar ciliated epithelium with goblet cells. Terminal bronchioles are covered by ciliated cuboidal epithelium. The alveolar duct, alveolar SAC, alveolae are covered by squamous epithelium and no goblet cells.

[image]

*The cartilage is present only untill the initial bronchioles.

image source: Laniece, Alexandra. (2018). Alveoli-on-a-chip : A close-contact dynamic model of the alveolar capillary barrier: micro-engineering, microfluidics and induced pluripotent stem cells.